# Making the garbage collector give up faster

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I'm looking at writing a program in Java that will repeatedly try a computation, note that it runs out of memory, change the computation, retry until it succeeds. (Running out of memory is unavoidable; roughly speaking, what I have in mind is like genetic programming, where you can't always tell in advance whether a generated program will run out of memory.) So looking at the main loop catching an out of memory error.

The following simple test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        hashMap.put(Integer.toBinaryString(i), i);
    }
    System.out.println(hashMap.size());
}
```

runs out of memory and exits with the uncaught exception as expected, but it takes about twenty minutes, most of which time seems to be spent by the garbage collector making heroic efforts to find enough memory to keep going.

How do I tell the garbage collector that I'm expecting to run out of memory and it should give up earlier?

Comment: Why? You want it to run out of memory when it hasn't?

Comment: @EJP You could put it that way. The way I'd put it is, when it's 90% out of memory and almost certainly going to run out entirely, I want it to give up early instead of spending twenty minutes of CPU time grinding through the remaining 10%.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for a particular method to inform garbage collector for advance notification about **out of memory**

But a below tricky would work to notify you instantly about **out of memory error**

Define a **initialCapacity**   for HashMap you would get **out of memory error** on run itself.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>(1000000000); // define initialCapacity
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                  hashMap.put(Integer.toBinaryString(i), i);
            }
            System.out.println(hashMap.size());
```

Comment: Sahi hai Raju ji :)

Comment: In this test case, true, but in practice it's not known in advance how many elements will be added.

Comment: The required memory is 75 times of the size of the `HashMap`. So, When the HashMap is constructed it is not guaranteed that it won't face `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: @rwallace if its not known in advance, how you will you tell the same to  garbage collector? its not be possible

Comment: @rwallace You should guess an approximate capacity. Otherwise, you will have lots of garbage generating while the HashMap resizes.

Comment: @RajuSharma I want to tell the garbage collector that when memory gets 90% full - something that cannot be predicted beforehand but could easily be measured by the GC when it happens - it should give up immediately and report out of memory instead of spending twenty minutes of CPU time eking out the last 10%.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the amount of memory you need and compare it to `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` to find out whether your algorithm has enough available memory or not. To calculate required memory you must consider:

- The capacity of your `HashMap` that as Raju said, must be passed to HashMap constructor to prevent generating garbage
- The average size of the Binary Strings that in your sample is about 29 characters or 58 bytes
- The size of an `Integer` for each item
- References sizes of any `Object` including `Strings` and `Integers`

For instance, the following code needs about 75 GB memory:

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>(1000000000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        hashMap.put(Integer.toBinaryString(i), i);
    }
    System.out.println(hashMap.size());
```

Moreover, if you dynamically change the size of your `Map` and its approximate capacity is not determined, you shouldn't use `HashMap` because its resizing produces garbage and you may have several resizing during your loop. Instead, you should use another `Map` like `TreeMap` that generates no garbage.

Comment: Sure, adding a fixed number of elements to a hash table it's easy to calculate the needed memory in advance, but that's just a trivial test program. For the real code, calculating the memory in advance is undecidable.

Comment: @rwallace I edited my answer suggesting using of `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: Ah, you're right, switching to `TreeMap` does make the test program run an order of magnitude faster, presumably for that reason. Interesting!

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do it. Don't let the JVM throw OOME and don't let it even come close to it as it always wastes time.

Instead of waiting for the OOME, ask `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` either periodically or in the loop and bail out before you get too close to zero (this needs some experiments).

---

No idea what's the overhead of calling `freeMemory()`, but if you need it in a tight loop, you can always do something like

```
if (i % 1000 == 0) {
    ... do the test
}
```

(or use `i << 22 == 0` as a much faster test for modulo 1024).

I'd probably go for a timer instead. You can also use `GarbageCollectorMXBean` to out how much time was spend in the GC (it's not exactly user friendly).

---

I would not try to compute the expected memory usage as this is hard and may easily break, when your code changes. Presizing the map and similar tricks are surely useful, but don't try too hard as the gain is limited. Consider improving the algorithm and/or using more compact data structures - that's also hard but may gain much more.

---

> I want to tell the garbage collector that when memory gets 90% full - something that cannot be predicted beforehand but could easily be measured by the GC when it happens - it should give up

Sure, just don't bother the GC, measure the memory yourself and bail out.